# Zend Framework 2 debug_backtrace()

Tags: php, zend-framework2, debug-backtrace

I'm having hard time using ZF2 because I cannot use debug_print_backtrace() like I would use it normally.

It is showing me huge amount of data from Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent object. Output looks something like this:

```
#1  Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent Object ( .... A LOT OF DATA
,[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu),[SERVER_NAME] => zf.localhost.com,[SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1,[SERVER_PORT] => 80, .... SOME SERVER PARAMETERS
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at zf.localhost.com Port 80
...
```

Is there a way to not show all this MvcEvent content but still see backtrace with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove the first row (i.e. the MvcEvent), remember - debug_backtrace() returns an array. Nothing prevents you from shifting or popping the data you don't want!

(array_shift() - removes the first element of an array. array_pop() - removes the last. They come in pretty handy in cases like these :-) )

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! It is one way to do it. But it will not help me in debug_print_backtrace(). Maybe there is another way to solve this?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't see you were using debug_print_backtrace, assumed you were using the array form.

Switch to the array returning function, or output-buffer the printout from debug_print_backtrace and edit out (using regular expressions or standard string functions) the values you don't want?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I will need to create some globally available debug_backtrace function that will filter backtrace results so it is usable again. I will accept your answer tomorrow if nothing better will show up. Cheers!

Comment: What I was getting at is that you can selectively kill parameters using a combination of both - i.e. stripping out parameters for the first part of the dump, but not for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have XDebug installed? I found XDebug invaluable whilst debugging ZF2 issues as you can limit the object depth displayed using var_dump and a few other commands.

An example of this and more information can be found at http://xdebug.org/docs/display

You could then use `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` for a less verbose output.